# Laravel retrieving data only for selected id

Tags: laravel-5

Currently i have app builded using:
- Models
    - Keyword
    - Video
- Repositories
    - VideoRepository
    - KeywordRepository
- Controllers
    - VideoController
    - KeywordController
Keyword and Video is pivoted

In KeywordController i would like to display Keywordlist only for selected video_id.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Models\Keyword;

use App\Repositories\KeywordRepository;

class KeywordController extends Controller
{
    public function index(KeywordRepository $keywordRepo, $video_id){

        $keywords = $keywordRepo->getAll();

        dump($keywords);


    }
```

At this moment i can't use find($video_id). Is there any way to use VideoRepository for retrieving correct video and than retrieve $keywordRepo elements for it?

Comment: you can use where statement with first() for get single record.

Answer (score 0):

```
$keywords = $keywordRepo->where('id',$video_id)->first();
```

Comment: In KeywordRepository i don't have where function. Also in BaseRepository i have  only getAll, create, update, delete, find. Should i create it and use DB?

Comment: what you write in find function?

Comment: public function find($id){
  return $this->model->find($id);
 }

Comment: public function find($id){ return Model::find($id); } (Model is your model where you want to find data. and make sure your find id is primary key)

Comment: if your $video_id is not primary key in Model so please you use where function in repository like:-  public function find($id) { User::where('video_id', $id)->first(); }